# FHIR - How to delete Vital Data

Tags: hl7-fhir

This link talks about how to write Vital information to FHIR database. [Write Vital on Smart on FHIR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470126/write-vital-on-smart-on-fhir)

As we are demonstrating our data collection capabilities we find that we get a large amount of database making our graphs look cluttered.

How do we delete a particular observation, a set of observations or all the observations for a given patient ID and LOINC code?

Answer (score 0):

Deletions are only handled on a resource by resource basis.  There's no ability to delete by "query".  So you'd have to do a query, find all the ids, then send requests to delete each record.  (Though you could do so using batch.) Instructions for delete are here: http://build.fhir.org/http.html#delete

Comment: You could use the conditional delete described in the instructions to delete multiple resources, if the server allows that.